# Adding images to placemarks multiple times

Tags: google-earth, image

I have a route that I travel that is saved by coordinates to a .csv file for use in GE.  I have images (pictures) that I would like to add to placemarks I have along the route.  Is there a script or macro I can run that would allow me to add the url of the images to the .csv file so that I could have the images appear inside the placemarks balloon without having to add the images individually to the balloon?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use **Time Album** for that purpose ([software and manual](http://www.columbus-gps.de/v-900_support.php))?

It's a small Java program designed to work with Columbus gps loggers and works with data in CSV format. It has a function to link pictures to gps tracks and export as KML. I'm not sure though if CSV data must be supplied in Columbus specified format but perhaps you could reorganize your data to fit into that.

Another option (on Windows machine) would be to use freeware [**GeoSetter**](http://www.geosetter.de/en/) (via [Directions Mag](http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/georeferencing-on-a-budget-using-iphone-and-freeware-apps-to-geotag-a-/270266))